# Convert 2 columns in a table into one for small display sizes using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to convert a table with 2 columns into table with 1 column for small display sizes using Bootstrap and no additional custom scripts?

I know how to make it but in case using just `div`'s instead of `table`.

Convert this :

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Column 1</td>
   <td>Column 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Into this

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Column 1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Column 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wrap your table using div tag with class of table-responsive. and in your table tag include a class of table. [table responsive](http://themergency.com/footable/) is also a good for setting breakpoints in your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive), this should work:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use responsive table like:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
<tr>
   <td>Column 1</td>
   <td>Column 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

see following link for more information:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: The OP is asking to convert table into DIV